# Get the number of variables in a splat ruby

Tags: ruby, splat

How can I count the number of values being passed as a splat argument while calling a method?

```
def splat_demo(*var)
   #code to find out no of values in the splat variable here
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get an array so just run `var.size` to get number of values that were passed in.

Comment: Didn't know I could use it as an array. Thank you!

Comment: You don't "use it as an array". It *is* an `Array`.